# Bike making squeaking sound while upshifting

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, shifting, noise, mv-agusta

I've put 7281 Kms on the bike so far and recently I've encountered a problem. While upshifting using the clutch, the bike makes a squeaking sound. The sound appears when I release the clutch. This problem has only apeared recently and does not apear if I use the quickshifter nor during downshifts.

My questions are:

1. Is this caused by a fault in the gearbox or is it something else?
2. Could this cause long term damage or worse, an accident?
3. Is there anyway to remedy this?

Bike in question: MV Agusta Brutale 675 MY 2014
Ussage: Primarily sport riding (cornering) and occasional commuting (rarely)

Comment: Is it while you hold a clutch lever or when you release it? Is it a long squeak or a short one? Or as long as you hold a clutch?

Comment: @Arturs Bolsunovskis it happens when I release the clutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid you will have to take your clutch cover off. Check your oil level before draining an oil, then drain it, and take a clutch cover off. Before that make sure you have a new clutch cover gasket and new oil. Something wears out in there, and as a bike engine it has an engine, clutch, and a gearbox all in one case, lubes with same oil, and bike engine is very delicate thing, engine oil pump will grab gearbox and clutch debris before it stops in oil filter. If it's not the clutch disengage lever, might be any washer behind a clutch. If you're not sure, ask for assistance in garage. Don't leave like this. 7000 km in racing mode is quiet a lot, normally racing engine (developed and 100% racing use) should be maintained at least once in 30 hours.

Answer (score 1):

**It's part of your shift linkage**

Here is a shift rod that transfers power from your shift left to your shift drum via the shaft that will rotate when you shift.

The shift rod has ball joints on either end.  This is the likely source of your squeak.  Use a lubricant on them, preferably a dry lubricant.

Once lubricated the sound should go away.

**Shift rod w/ ball joints**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. For some reason the squeaking seems to have disapeared by itself. But I will be sure to check my shift lingkage.

Comment: It's almost always the ball joints.  Good luck!